# Не работает celery (Process exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'.)

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

Задача находится в models.py

```
@task
def send(text):
    try:
        bot = telebot.TeleBot('token******')

        for user in BotUser.objects.all():

            try:
                bot.send_message(user.chat_id, text)
            except:
                pass

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        bot.send_message(359144124, str(e))


class Dispatch(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Рассылка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Рассылка'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            send.apply_async((self.text,))

        super(Dispatch, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

вот celery файл

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.conf import settings


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'franch2.settings')

app = Celery('franch2')


app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

При запуске `celery -A franch2 worker -l info`

получаю следующее

```
 -------------- celery@cs158429 v4.1.0 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-103-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2017-12-19 01:14:44
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         franch2:0x7f06e71b4f28
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . bot.models.send

[2017-12-19 01:14:44,648: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2017-12-19 01:14:44,660: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2017-12-19 01:14:45,706: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-12-19 01:14:45,731: INFO/MainProcess] celery@cs158429 ready.
[2017-12-19 01:15:25,830: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-1' pid:16260 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

UPD

При вводе команды `dmesg | egrep -i 'killed process'` показывает что убивает celery процесс

```
[437345.098869] gunicorn invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24201ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[437345.098872] gunicorn cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[437345.098877] CPU: 0 PID: 7453 Comm: gunicorn Not tainted 4.4.0-103-generic #126-Ubuntu
[437345.098878] Hardware name: Bochs Bochs, BIOS Bochs 01/01/2011
[437345.098880]  0000000000000286 34b84a49fd0bed1a ffff88001a8df9d8 ffffffff813fb523
[437345.098882]  ffff88001a8dfb90 ffff88001d9d8000 ffff88001a8dfa48 ffffffff8120cb7e
[437345.098884]  ffffffff81cd7a2f 0000000000000000 ffffffff81e67920 0000000000000206
[437345.098886] Call Trace:
[437345.098892]  [<ffffffff813fb523>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[437345.098896]  [<ffffffff8120cb7e>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
[437345.098899]  [<ffffffff81193562>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
[437345.098901]  [<ffffffff81193989>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
[437345.098904]  [<ffffffff81199995>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x965/0xb00
[437345.098906]  [<ffffffff81199db6>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x286/0x2a0
[437345.098911]  [<ffffffff811e38bc>] alloc_pages_current+0x8c/0x110
[437345.098913]  [<ffffffff8118fb2b>] __page_cache_alloc+0xab/0xc0
[437345.098914]  [<ffffffff8119203a>] filemap_fault+0x14a/0x3f0
[437345.098918]  [<ffffffff812a5046>] ext4_filemap_fault+0x36/0x50
[437345.098922]  [<ffffffff811befd0>] __do_fault+0x50/0xe0
[437345.098924]  [<ffffffff811c2af2>] handle_mm_fault+0xfa2/0x1820
[437345.098927]  [<ffffffff8106b577>] __do_page_fault+0x197/0x400
[437345.098929]  [<ffffffff8106b847>] trace_do_page_fault+0x37/0xe0
[437345.098932]  [<ffffffff81063f29>] do_async_page_fault+0x19/0x70
[437345.098935]  [<ffffffff81846a28>] async_page_fault+0x28/0x30
[437345.098936] Mem-Info:
[437345.098946] active_anon:109494 inactive_anon:2640 isolated_anon:0
                 active_file:309 inactive_file:434 isolated_file:0
                 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
                 slab_reclaimable:2537 slab_unreclaimable:2733
                 mapped:3609 shmem:5297 pagetables:2305 bounce:0
                 free:2110 free_pcp:59 free_cma:0
[437345.098948] Node 0 DMA free:3880kB min:92kB low:112kB high:136kB active_anon:10340kB inactive_anon:312kB active_file:16kB inactive_file:96kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:396kB shmem:600kB slab_reclaimable:368kB slab_unreclaimable:424kB kernel_stack:32kB pagetables:228kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:684 all_unreclaimable? yes
[437345.098954] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 436 436 436 436
[437345.098956] Node 0 DMA32 free:4560kB min:2624kB low:3280kB high:3936kB active_anon:427636kB inactive_anon:10248kB active_file:1220kB inactive_file:1640kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:507884kB managed:484136kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:14040kB shmem:20588kB slab_reclaimable:9780kB slab_unreclaimable:10508kB kernel_stack:2208kB pagetables:8992kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:236kB local_pcp:236kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:38660 all_unreclaimable? yes
[437345.098961] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[437345.098964] Node 0 DMA: 4*4kB (UM) 13*8kB (UMH) 15*16kB (UMH) 12*32kB (U) 21*64kB (UMEH) 8*128kB (UMEH) 3*256kB (MH) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3880kB
[437345.098971] Node 0 DMA32: 110*4kB (ME) 209*8kB (UME) 29*16kB (UME) 0*32kB 1*64kB (H) 1*128kB (H) 1*256kB (H) 1*512kB (H) 1*1024kB (H) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 4560kB
[437345.098978] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[437345.098980] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[437345.098980] 6042 total pagecache pages
[437345.098982] 0 pages in swap cache
[437345.098983] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[437345.098984] Free swap  = 0kB
[437345.098984] Total swap = 0kB
[437345.098985] 130969 pages RAM
[437345.098986] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[437345.098986] 5958 pages reserved
[437345.098987] 0 pages cma reserved
[437345.098988] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[437345.098989] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[437345.098992] [  209]     0   209     9077      618      20       3        0             0 systemd-journal
[437345.098994] [  257]     0   257    11069      173      23       3        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
[437345.098996] [  377]     0   377    69318      176      38       3        0             0 accounts-daemon
[437345.098997] [  378]   106   378    10723      112      27       3        0          -900 dbus-daemon
[437345.098999] [  387]   104   387    64099      407      27       3        0             0 rsyslogd
[437345.099000] [  400]     0   400     7137       80      20       3        0             0 systemd-logind
[437345.099002] [  402]     0   402     7630       70      20       4        0             0 cron
[437345.099003] [  486]   109   486    74054     2958      68       3        0          -900 postgres
[437345.099005] [  518]     0   518     4030      216      12       3        0             0 dhclient
[437345.099006] [  547]   109   547    74087     1582      64       3        0             0 postgres
[437345.099007] [  548]   109   548    74054      531      59       3        0             0 postgres
[437345.099009] [  549]   109   549    74054     1056      60       3        0             0 postgres
[437345.099010] [  550]   109   550    74148      510      62       3        0             0 postgres
[437345.099012] [  551]   109   551    37834      473      55       3        0             0 postgres
[437345.099013] [  621]  1000   621    17773     3757      41       3        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099015] [  652]   110   652    10412      223      14       3        0             0 redis-server
[437345.099016] [  690]     0   690     4317       37      14       3        0             0 agetty
[437345.099018] [ 1008]     0  1008    16380      181      35       3        0         -1000 sshd
[437345.099019] [ 1009]     0  1009     4363       34      13       3        0             0 agetty
[437345.099021] [ 1117]     0  1117    31277      367      44       3        0             0 nginx
[437345.099022] [ 1118]    33  1118    31452      522      47       3        0             0 nginx
[437345.099023] [ 1388]  1000  1388    17806     3757      39       4        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099025] [32631]  1000 32631    42429     8760      86       3        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099026] [14663]  1000 14663   117095     9184      96       4        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099028] [15122]  1000 15122    79632     9138      91       3        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099029] [20096]  1000 20096   117362     9444      97       4        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099031] [ 8909]   100  8909    24023       54      16       3        0             0 systemd-timesyn
[437345.099032] [10649]  1000 10649   192929    10801     106       4        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099034] [16069]     0 16069    23850      249      50       3        0             0 sshd
[437345.099035] [16071]     0 16071     9200      187      23       3        0             0 systemd
[437345.099037] [16076]     0 16076    52157      492      37       3        0             0 (sd-pam)
[437345.099038] [16099]     0 16099     5942      388      17       3        0             0 bash
[437345.099039] [16115]  1000 16115    44653    10479      87       4        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099041] [16127]  1000 16127    44158    10006      85       4        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099042] [16139]     0 16139    13449      105      31       3        0             0 su
[437345.099044] [16140]  1000 16140     5967      416      17       3        0             0 bash
[437345.099045] [16161]  1000 16161    45644    10569      92       3        0             0 celery
[437345.099047] [16256]  1000 16256    44498    11402      90       3        0             0 celery
[437345.099048] [16281]  1000 16281    43959     9770      84       4        0             0 gunicorn
[437345.099049] [16456]     0 16456    23850      237      49       3        0             0 sshd
[437345.099051] [16478]     0 16478     5942      388      16       3        0             0 bash
[437345.099052] [16492]     0 16492    23850      235      50       3        0             0 sshd
[437345.099054] [16513]     0 16513     5942      389      16       3        0             0 bash
[437345.099055] [16527]     0 16527    13449      104      32       3        0             0 su
[437345.099056] [16528]  1000 16528     5960      408      17       4        0             0 bash
[437345.099058] [16547]     0 16547    13449      105      32       3        0             0 su
[437345.099059] [16548]  1000 16548     5934      381      17       3        0             0 bash
[437345.099060] [16558]  1000 16558     5934      382      15       3        0             0 bash
[437345.099062] [16559]  1000 16559    15504     1406      33       3        0             0 command-not-fou
[437345.099063] [16560]     0 16560    16380      179      36       3        0             0 sshd
[437345.099065] [16562]   109 16562    74129      478      60       3        0             0 postgres
[437345.099066] Out of memory: Kill process 16256 (celery) score 91 or sacrifice child
[437345.100812] Killed process 16256 (celery) total-vm:177992kB, anon-rss:45608kB, file-rss:0kB
```

Comment: Вот такое нашлось: https://github.com/getredash/redash/issues/812 То есть, возможно процесс съедает всю память и убивается OOM Killer/Reaper.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov спасибо за ответ! Причина может и такая, но , увы,  я там не смог найти решение :с

Comment: У тебя порожденный процесс отел много памяти, "в системе стало тесно и ядро его убило". Из вариантов решения IMHO:
1. (лучше) запусти profiler и найти узкие места – оптимизируй.
2. (в лоб) создай большой swap на fs – `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap.img bs=1M count=16384 && mkswap /swap.img && swapon /swap.img`